# How do I find a text string within a group in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, search, editor

In Xcode, it is easy to find a text string within  a file (`cmd+f`) or within a project (`cmd+shift+f`). Is it possible to perform a localised search within a group from within the IDE?

**EDIT**

If this is not possible, is there a way to format the search results into groups? An alphabetical list of files under the header . . .

> 6751 results in 424 files

. . is not useful for a human :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot search just in one group. When you search using cmd+shift+f, you should be able to see which file all the matches are from, so it's not really necessary to be able to search a group. I actually don't know of an IDE that has that feature.

Comment: It is pretty necessary when the project has a **lot** of source files.  It would be useful if whole-project-search results were at least returned by group.

Comment: I can see why you want it, but Xcode doesn't have that feature. You might consider using multiple projects or static libraries to modularize your code.